# PHP / AJAX user last online displayed in real time

Tags: php, ajax

I have a good piece of code that shows how many users are online using sessions from a table named 'online_users'.

I'm using AJAX to return my data on to my home PHP page (this works; I just need the method to check each online client changed).

[Here is a picture of my current styling using the first code method below](https://gyazo.com/e737916c0057107bfaa6de1128fb8ea5)

[Here is a picture of my 'Online_users' table in my database](https://gyazo.com/a0a6e78565f32b47b6cc94a8a8ab17b6)

I need to use the same method of this code to check each users online time.

At the moment, it only counts how many users are online.

I also have another piece of code to check, but it doesn't run the same way as the second method (the method that gets online users count). This one shows offline if a timer has passed. I need to make it work the same way as the count online users method (Method 2 in the code below) so it checks sessions in my database.

I need to make it so the each individual user check does it the same way by checking the session in my table 'online_users'.

My 1st code (Working but changes to offline after a certain amount of time instead of checking if the session is still active) :

```
//First, define our client_is_online so we don't throw errors in the while loop
$client_is_online = "";

//Get online users individually and echo if they're online or not in a div class
$user_grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");
while($users_ = mysqli_fetch_array($user_grab)) {

$last_online = strtotime($users_['lastonline']);

if(time() - $last_online < 30) {
    $client_is_online .= '
         <div class="chat-list-item sidebar-tab -available" data-target="#chat-view-tab" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); padding: 5px;">
            <img class="chat-list-avatar" src="'.$users_['profile_picture'].'" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding: 7px; border-radius: 20px;" /><i class="fa fa-circle chat-list-status"> </i>
            <div class="chat-list-user">'.$users_['username'].' (<font size="2">'.get_users_level_all($users_['userLevel']).'</font>)</div>
            <div class="chat-list-excerpt">Online</div>
         </div>
    ';
} else {
    $client_is_online .= '
         <div class="chat-list-item sidebar-tab -away" data-target="#chat-view-tab" style="background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); padding: 5px;">
            <img class="chat-list-avatar" src="'.$users_['profile_picture'].'" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding: 7px; border-radius: 20px;" /><i class="fa fa-circle chat-list-status"> </i>
            <div class="chat-list-user">'.$users_['username'].' (<font size="2">'.get_users_level_all($users_['userLevel']).'</font>)</div>
            <div class="chat-list-excerpt">Offline</div>
         </div>
    ';
}
}
```

My 2nd code (Get count of online users - Works perfectly but I need to use this sort of way for checking if each individual user is online) :

```
//Count online users
$session = session_id(); $time = time(); $time_check = $time - 30; //We have set a check of 30 seconds
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM online_users WHERE session = '$session'");
$count  = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

if($count == '0') { $result1 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO online_users(session, time) VALUES ('$session', '$time')"); }
else { $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE online_users SET time = '$time' WHERE session = '$session'"); }

$result3     = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM online_users");
$totalOnline = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
$result4     = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM online_users WHERE time < $time_check");
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should use WebSocket and Redis instead

Querying database like this can make your application slow and consume more data

Read more

Redis Link >> [Redis](https://redis.io) 
WebSocket Link>> [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)